# PyQGIS (3.6.3 Noosa) Why is self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent() being overridden in plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, extents, mapcanvas

I am writing a plugin that first adds the Google Imagery XYZ tile layer and then adds various other layers - some from a GeoPackage and others by creating their geometry in PyQGIS.

The last function of the plugin is to zoom to one of my created layers. However, no matter what I try, the map canvas shows the entire world (extent of the tile layer).

Printing the `mapCanvas().extent()` at the end of the plugin `execute` function returns the desired extent, but the map shows the tile layer extent.

I have tried without the tile layer and the canvas is set to the extent of the layer with the largest extent.

I have a push button in my plugin dockwidget that zooms to the layer extent using exactly the same functionality that is at the end of my plugin execute function. The button works fine after the plugin has finished processing.

```py
# add the tile layer before the plugin does its processing
tile_url = 'type=xyz&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(tile_url, 'Google imagery', 'wms')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)

# after a few seconds processing the canvas is supposed to zoom to the layer extent
# the print statements give the same extent but the canvas is showing the entire tile layer (or layer with largest extent)
# lyr is a vector layer being generated when the main function of the plugin is run. 
# The following lines are at the end of the same function.

print(lyr.extent())
self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(lyr.extent())
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
print(self.iface.mapCanvas().extent())
```

Is there a reason why the `self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent()` is being overridden?

Comment: I get the same problem on qgis 3.22.4. The setExtent() function only works when it is called from a button.